# How to insert a Null Value to a column if there is no data provided from source file in ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am inserting data from a Text file to table.

and the SPROC is as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPROC]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @DBName VARCHAR(30),
    @FirstLine VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @InsertQuery NVARCHAR(MAX), @Summary_ID INT

        SET @InsertQuery = 'INSERT INTO ' + @DBName + '.[dbo].[Summary] VALUES ( ' + @FirstLine + '); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()'

        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @InsertQuery


    END
```

Now the thing is, if it has 8 values it will get inserted. If 8 th Value is not there in the text file it is throwing Error **column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition**

How can i handle this error and If there is no value for 8th column it should insert the value as NULL.

Reading File code:

```
public static String[] ReadSummary_Into_Array(string filepath)
        {
            StreamReader sreader = null;
            int counter = 0;
            try
            {
                sreader = new StreamReader(filepath);

                string line = sreader.ReadLine();
                //condition to hanlde empty file
                if (line == null) return null;

                //condition to hanlde empty first line file
                if (line == "") return new String[0];

                FirstLine = line;

                string cleaned_line = line.Replace("''", "'-'").Replace("','", "''");
                string word = "";
                List<string> data = new List<string>();

                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(cleaned_line, @"'([^']*)");
                //String[] words = null;

                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    word = match.ToString();
                    string word_edited = word.Replace("\'", "");

                    if (word_edited != string.Empty)
                    {
                        data.Add(word_edited);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                Summary = new String[counter];

                Summary = data.ToArray(); //The Summary Line is reconstructed into a String array

                return Summary;

            }
```

Comment: `I am inserting data from a Text file to table.` How are you doing that?
How are you reading the text file and calling the SPROC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have `value` then you must specify the column names.

Try like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPROC]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @DBName VARCHAR(30),
    @FirstLine VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @InsertQuery NVARCHAR(MAX), @Summary_ID INT, @CountS INT

        SET @CountS = len(@FirstLine) - len(replace(@FirstLine, ',', ''))

        IF @CountS >= 7 THEN

              SET @InsertQuery = 'INSERT INTO ' + @DBName + '.[dbo].[Summary] VALUES ( ' + @FirstLine + '); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
        ELSE

              SET @InsertQuery = 'INSERT INTO ' + @DBName + '.[dbo].[Summary](SerialNumber,AssetNumber,SoftwareRev,TechName,StartTime,StopTime,Status) VALUES ( ' + @FirstLine + '); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()'    
        END IF 

        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @InsertQuery      
    END
```

Comment: Thank you So much Vignesh Kumar.. My Problem got solved. From morning itself I am trying to solve this through code behind. Finally You helped me. Thank YOu

Comment: @SreerangaVinjamuri Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Similar as Vignesh, but in your C# code

```
if ( Regex.Matches( strLine,  "," ).Count == 7)
 {
    strLine  = strLine + ', null';
 }
```